# Clone SpreadsheetGear worksheet

Tags: wpf, clone, worksheet, spreadsheetgear

How to copy and duplicate an existing IWorksheet object in SpreadsheetGear?

I want to make identical worksheet based on another worksheet (all values, formulas, named ranges etc. should follow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ISheet.[CopyAfter](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.ISheet~CopyAfter.html)/[CopyBefore](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.ISheet~CopyBefore.html) methods to copy a single sheet, in its entirety and including named ranges, to some other location.  This "other location" could be within the same workbook as the sheet you are copying; or an entirely different workbook.  Example:

```
// Make copy of "Sheet1" in sourceWorkbook after "Sheet3" in destWorkbook
IWorksheet newSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].CopyAfter(destWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet3"]);
```

Comment: What if the destination Workbook is in another WorkbookView? I have <sprgr:WorkbookView Name="wbw1"/> and <sprgr:WorkbookView Name="wbw2"/> and want to copy Worksheet from wbw1 to wbw2. I am getting an exeption when trying to do that.

Comment: It should not matter whether the destination workbook is attached to another WorkbookView or not.  You should probably post a new question with a specific test case demonstrating the problem.